# Is there an alternative to the squeeze theorem when dealing with oscillating functions multiplied by 0?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The general question that I have is if there is a limit $\lim_{x->n}f(x)g(x)$ such that $\lim_{x->n}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x->n}g(x)$ is undefined due to oscillatory behavior (This is assumed to be because some function I(x) is oscillatory with a range such that $R\in\Bbb{R}$ and a function L(x) with an asymptote at n with both sides of the function near n being continuous is written like I(L(x)) and equal to g(x)), is it possible to come to the conclusion that $\lim_{x->n}f(x)g(x)=0$ without ever using the squeeze theorem. The reason why I ask it in relation to the squeeze theorem is because commonly an expression like $\lim_{x->0}xcos(1/x)$ is pretty common and one would use the squeeze theorem to solve it. The proofs to solve these limits starts fairly easily but as the functions get more complicated there is more and more theory involved.The main reason that I asked that general question is because I thought of a fairly intuitive way to solve the general case which is to break done the limit of I(L(x)).

First write $\lim_{x->n}I(L(x))$ like $I(\lim_{x->n}L(x))$ and knowing that the left and right limits of L(x) exist as $\infty$ or $-\infty$ assume that the total limit is $\infty$ or $-\infty$.
then $\lim_{x->n}L(I(x))=I(\infty,-\infty)$ which is indeterminate but going back to the general limit we now have $\lim_{x->n}f(x)I(\infty,-\infty)$ which the lim of f(x) at n is defined to be 0 so now we have $0I(\infty,-\infty)$.Now because I(x) is an oscillatory function with a range such that $R\in\Bbb{R}$ the function stays inside such a range even when going to infinity and recall that $0A=0$ when $A\in\Bbb{R}$ and because I(x) must exist within its range R than $0I(\infty,-\infty)=0$.

I know that my proof has many flaws in it, but I would like to know if the general limit is solvable with a method that isn't based off the squeeze theorem. The way I wrote may seem convoluted so if anyone can word it in a neater fashion please do.